# What is this fastener? Brass colored, three slots of some type. (And how to remove it?)

Tags: fasteners

Here's a close up:

[image]

This vehicle license-plate holder uses three of them: Unfortunately I can't see behind.

[image]

*Note, ignore the four small dimples on the plastic arranged rectangularly; unrelated.*

What is this strange fastener and how to remove it ?

I've had screwdrivers with "tri tips" (for example, there are true tri-tip screws on a Nintendo Switch game console) but this looks different...

Comment: ask the auto dealer service department

Comment: Regardless of what it is, you can drill it out

Comment: it's probably a pin ... hook something under the head and pull it out

Comment: @jsotola - ah that simple?!  TBC by head you mean the "brassy colored part" ... ?

Comment: yes ... it's only a guess though

Answer (score 2):

I would think that is one of those wide headed fixings with 3 "ears" that expand when the central pin is pushed in.

Usually, to remove, you push the pin all the way through and then you can pull that fixing out as the "ears" then can collapse towards the axial centre as the pin is no longer there.

If you do a search for"trim fixing clips" you will see a variety around that theme I described.

Comment: brilliant!  you'd think ... there'd be a special rivet-removing tool ?  By push through, you mean, if I stick something in there I'll feel something - and that's the thing to push through?

Answer (score 1):

Solar Mike is right, this is a *rivet* and the only way to remove it is to pull really hard on the plastic surrounding it, or wedge a screwdriver blade under the plastic part and pry it loose from the hole in the sheet metal into which the rivet was pressed.

Comment: Got it, damn, the problem here is - it's plastic on plastic.  (the plate-holder-thing is plastic and the bumper itself is plastic)  any sort of pull/wedging will result in disaster!

Comment: Well then, you gotta DRILL, BABY! DRILL!

Comment: got it. just any old (maybe "for metal") drill bit of not-too-much-bigger?

Comment: also .. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/90455/36606